# How to create a Samba share available from Windows 10, read only, for my friends to map it as a network drive and be able to play movies from?

Tags: ubuntu, samba, file-sharing

I have a VPS on Linode with Samba installed on it.

I want to create a Samba share on this VPS, where I'll put some videos from holiday and some pictures.
I'd like this files be available read only to some 20 people - friends and family without authentication. So it's easy for them to play these videos and watch these photos on their local computers.

I've already created a Samba share based on this video:
https://youtu.be/7Q0mnAT1MRg

I did most of the things the same as shown on the video, but I want to create a Samba share inside my Linux home folder: `/home/michal/movies/`.

Therefore instead of putting `user:smbuser` and `group:smbgroup` in my `smb.conf` I used the username I currently use to login into my Ubuntu VPS, which is:`michal`.
I did that to save some changing on permissions, directory owner and directory group.

```
michal@ubuntu:~$ ls -lah /home/michal/ | grep "^d"
drwxr-xr-x 10 michal michal 4.0K Nov 12 21:35 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root   4.0K Oct  7  2021 ..
drwxrwxr-x 63 michal michal 4.0K Nov  8 22:22 100DaysOfCode
drwx------  2 michal michal 4.0K Oct  3  2021 .cache
drwx------  4 michal michal 4.0K Mar 22  2022 .config
drwxrwxr-x  4 michal michal 4.0K Feb  3  2022 endlessh
drwxrwxr-- 12 michal michal 4.0K Nov 12 00:33 movies
drwxrwxr--  2 michal michal 4.0K May 31 12:55 photos
drwxrwxr-x  2 michal michal 4.0K Jun 26 22:39 .ssh
drwxrwxr-x  5 michal michal 4.0K Nov  8 21:52 .vscode-server
```

This is how my `smb.conf` file looks like:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h movies server (Samba, Ubuntu)
security = user
name resolve order = bcast host
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
logging = file
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role = standalone server
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
usershare allow guests = yes

[roes_movies]
path = /home/michal/movies/
force user = michal
# force user = smbuser
force group = michal
# force group = smbgroup
# guest ok = yes
create mask = 0774
force create mode = 0774
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
public = yes
writable = no

# Note that "guest ok = yes" is a synonym for "public = yes"
```

To say the truth I don't understand why a separate user/group needs to be created for Samba service.
Why can't I just assign "michal" user and "michal" group, which already existed before, in my `smb.conf` file.

```
root@ubuntu:~# root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-network:x:100:102:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-resolve:x:101:103:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:102:104:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
messagebus:x:103:106::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
syslog:x:104:110::/home/syslog:/usr/sbin/nologin
_apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
tss:x:106:111:TPM software stack,,,:/var/lib/tpm:/bin/false
uuidd:x:107:112::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin
tcpdump:x:108:113::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
usbmux:x:109:46:usbmux daemon,,,:/var/lib/usbmux:/usr/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:110:65534::/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
landscape:x:111:115::/var/lib/landscape:/usr/sbin/nologin
pollinate:x:112:1::/var/cache/pollinate:/bin/false
systemd-coredump:x:999:999:systemd Core Dumper:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
michal:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/michal:/bin/bash
leon:x:1001:1001:leon,,,:/home/leon:/bin/bash
mssql:x:998:998::/var/opt/mssql:/bin/bash
asia:x:1002:1002:asia,,,:/home/asia:/bin/bash
fwupd-refresh:x:113:120:fwupd-refresh user,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
smbuser:x:997:997::/home/smbuser:/bin/false
```

These are the groups on my Ubuntu virtual server:

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/group
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:syslog
tty:x:5:syslog
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
news:x:9:
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:michal,leon,asia
audio:x:29:
dip:x:30:
www-data:x:33:
backup:x:34:
operator:x:37:
list:x:38:
irc:x:39:
src:x:40:
gnats:x:41:
shadow:x:42:
utmp:x:43:
video:x:44:
sasl:x:45:
plugdev:x:46:
staff:x:50:
games:x:60:
users:x:100:
nogroup:x:65534:
systemd-journal:x:101:
systemd-network:x:102:
systemd-resolve:x:103:
systemd-timesync:x:104:
crontab:x:105:
messagebus:x:106:
input:x:107:
kvm:x:108:
render:x:109:
syslog:x:110:
tss:x:111:
uuidd:x:112:
tcpdump:x:113:
landscape:x:115:
systemd-coredump:x:999:
michal:x:1000:smbuser
leon:x:1001:
mssql:x:998:
asia:x:1002:
mlocate:x:116:
ssl-cert:x:117:
sgx:x:118:
plocate:x:119:
_ssh:x:114:
fwupd-refresh:x:120:
rdma:x:121:
sambashare:x:122:
smbuser:x:997:
```

I have also run the `testparm` to check for errors in the `smb.conf` file.

```
root@ubuntu:~# testparm -v
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions
```

Comment: The important question is, how is your system going to be able to tell your 20 friends from the 5 billion or so other internet users? Without authentication, the only remaining way would be by IP addresses. And to prevent a careless home user from accidentally becoming a "Patient Zero" for various SMB-enabled malware, some Internet providers will block the ports used for Windows/Samba sharing in both in- and outgoing directions, so there is no guarantee a home user can connect to Windows/Samba fileshares outside their own local network.

Comment: @telcoM I'm only a beginner in Linux and networking and I don't think I've understood your point. Am I misusing Samba to do something it's not intended 2 do? My goal is not to restrict access to some specified group of people. I want to give a free, ONLY READ, access to the folder and all of its contents. Currently I don't even know if I did that successfully or not. I cannot access this Samba share myself from my local Windows machine. I don't know which tools should I use. Most tutorials explain how to find shared folder inside local area network, while I need to map it over internet.

Comment: There's a lot of things your tutorial does not cover that must be understood if you want to achieve your aim with Samba: the firewall of your VPS, the likely use of NAT and operator-configured port restrictions on your friends' internet connections, and the possible firewalls on their modems/routers and computers. Any of those **can block** Samba access, many of them **will probably do so by default**, and some of those things you can't even change at all. Setting up a very simple HTTP web server would have a much higher chance of being usable for an average home user.

Comment: https/nginx with http auth is a much better idea. Samba is not **meant** to be exposed to the WWW. It's had over several dozen remote root vulnerabilities over the past two decades.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for this info. More and more people are telling me that Samba is not meant to be exposed to the WWW. Slowly this notion is reaching my mind and I accept the fact that Samba is not the tool to achieve my goal. Can you please write two more sentences about this "https/nginx with http auth"?? Maybe drop me some youtube video or an article describing little more in detail, how could I achieve my goal using this NGINX server? Currently I have a website that sits on Apache server.
Do I need 2 change this to NGINX or can the website use Apache and I'll use NGINX 4 sharing?

Comment: https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=nginx+http+auth 

https://techexpert.tips/nginx/enable-https-nginx/

https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/ I strongly recommend disabling HTTP port 80.